# Converting kneading recipe to no knead recipe

Tags: baking, bread, kneading

I'm a beginning baker planning to make ensaymada, which has a sweet buttery dough. The [recipe](https://www.foxyfolksy.com/ensaymada-recipe/) I found requires kneading. Do I have to make some adjustments to the recipe, or can I just make the dough, let it rise for 2 hours, and then put it in the fridge as Gemma Stafford did for her [cinnamon rolls](https://www.biggerbolderbaking.com/cinnamon-rolls/)? According to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81595/to-knead-or-not-to-knead-that-is-the-question), someone made a no knead recipe out of a regular recipe without any changes other than letting the bread sit. Will this work or do I have to add more liquid? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert by any means, but my understanding of the no-knead process is that it really is just TIME that makes all the difference. I do not think you would need to alter the amount of liquid in your recipe. The time is just for the yeast to do its thing and develop flavor in your dough. Kneading accelerates the process, but if you have the time to allow the dough to sit, you can achieve the same thing with less hands-on work.

Answer (score 1):

No knead breads follow a high hydration recipe. The typical baker’s percentage for no-knead bread is 75% (meaning for every 100 g flour, you use 75g water).

Based on your recipe, i think it might have enough hydration to try the no knead option. I think you can try blending all the liquid ingredients (and also melted butter and sugar) and then move on to preparing your dough.

Comment: I have yet to try the recipe. Maybe I will make two batches, one with kneading and the other without and post the results here. Thanks a lot.